# Javascript Ajax - Contact form does not display prompts and send button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I was looking on different examples for contact form sent using Javascript / AJAX. but the solutions don't seems to work. I'm trying to rewrite an existing chunk of code. Here is what I was left with (with a few of my own modifications).

I don't quite understand that where the functionality was going wrong. The send button does nothing, does not send to email and just goes to the top of the page.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        if (name == "") {
           $('.errormess').html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Please Insert Your name</strong></div>'); 
           return false;
        }
        if (email == "") {
           $('.errormess').html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Please Insert Your Email</strong></div>'); 
           return false;
        }
        if (phone == "") {
           $('.errormess').html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Please Insert Your Phone Number</strong></div>'); 
           return false;
        }
        if (message == "") {
           $('.errormess').html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Please Insert Some Text</strong></div>'); 
           return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'contact-us.php',
            data: 'name='+$("#name").val() + 
            'email='+$("#email").val() + 
            'phone=' + $("#phone").val()
             + 'message=' + $("#message").val(),
            dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
          if (data == 0) {
          $('.errormess').html('<div class="alert alert-Success"><strong>Your Query Submited Successfully</strong></div>');
            } else {  
               $('.errormess').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Failed To Send the Email</strong></div>'); 
            }
          }
         });
        return true;
        });
```

This is the contact-us.php:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$to = "help@belladonnait.com";
$subject = "Email From User";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Email From User</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains User Requirement</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Message</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>".$name."</td>
<td>".$email."</td>
<td>".$phone."</td>
<td>".$message."</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

$ok=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if ($ok) {
    echo "1";
}
else{
    echo "0";
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to use the developer tools in the browser to track the request (network tab). Do you see it? What is the status code it returns?

Comment: Sorry I don't see what you're referring to. Is the "developer tools" in the network tab in stack overflow or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I think the the problem is with your data in ajax. Either send it in object from like {name:$("#name").val(),email:$("#name").val(),...} or add "&" in-front of each key like ( '&name='+$("#name").val() + '&email='+$("#email").val()  ). Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Dushant, I changed the script in ajax to: $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'contact-us.php',
           data: {
            name: nameVal,
       email: emailVal,
       phone: phoneVal,
       message: messageVal
           },
           dataType: 'json'

it still didn't seem to work